# how to Update gcc of OpenSuse 11.2?

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc, opensuse

I have OpenSuse 11.2 with gcc version 4.4.1. I would like to update my gcc version to 4.5.1. I have downloaded gcc-4.5-19.1.i586.rpm. When I rpm install it, it's asking for gcc45-4.5.1_20101208-9.8.i586.rpm which is a dependency so I downloaded it. Now when I rpm install gcc45, it's asking for a lot of dependencies.

I remember downloading gcc 4.3 and it's dependencies for Opensuse 11.2 through yaST :

```
YaST --install  automake autoconf libtool gcc gcc43 gcc43-c++\
gcc-c++ libcom_err-devel alsa-devel docbook5-xsl-stylesheets\
texlive texlive-bin libxml2-devel zlib-devel gettext-tools\
readline-devel ncurses-devel libstdc++43-devel\
glibc-devel linux-kernel-headers gperf indent doxygen\
xorg-x11-fonts-devel xorg-x11-libX11-devel xorg-x11-libXau-devel\
xorg-x11-libxcb-devel xorg-x11-libXdmcp-devel xorg-x11-proto-devel\
xorg-x11-xtrans-devel xorg-x11-util-devel bison cvs
```

What about for gcc 4.5 ? how do I download it's dependencies for 11.2?

Comment: Please note that openSUSE 11.2 is no longer supported. I recommend you to upgrade to latest release, which is 11.4.

Comment: I have a program which compiles just fine in OpenSuse 11.2 with QT version 4.5. However, when I compiled the same program using OpenSuse 11.4 with QT 4.7.3 (required), I'm getting this error message:

: fatal error: > QtXmlPatterns/QXmlSchema: No such file or directory
I have these files in my usr and toolchain folders. I wonder why it can't be found. So I was thinking, maybe I could just update QT and GCC version of Opensuse 11.2.

Comment: the QXmlSchema class was added in Qt4.6 so I'm not sure how you had it in 4.5.  Did you have the devel package installed?  Headers are found there.

Comment: @jonescb: yup, I have the devel package installed as well ...

Answer (score 2):

You might find the OpenSUSE Build Service useful; there are [packages in the `devel:gcc` project](https://build.opensuse.org/package/show?package=gcc45&project=devel%3Agcc).

I believe if you add the URL http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/devel:/gcc/openSUSE_11.2/ to your YaST configuration, you ought to be able to install those packages. (Though the status on the website looks *broken*, I wonder how long that'll be..)

All that said, I'd like to suggest that you *not* do your upgrade; SuSE goes to some effort to rebuild the entire distribution with the specific compiler *and not break ABI compatibility with updates*. Changing versions wholesale *might* break ABI compatibility with tools you compile, and either require rebuilding system-installed libraries, or backing out the changes.

If you can just upgrade the distribution to one that supports the gcc 4.5 branch, that'd be a safer option. (No, I've never personally seen ABI breakage when upgrading the compiler. But that doesn't mean it won't happen to you. :)